# Does Google search console assume there must be a retina image?

Tags: seo, google-search-console

We noticed a considerable proportion of 404-s in Crawl stats report and upon inspection it turns out that pretty much all the images on our WP blog yield a 404 for their "retina" version, i.e. `https://example.com/blog/image@2x.jpg`. We do not supply a retina version in our markup currently, and I don't think we ever did. Is there a reason that you know of that Google thinks there must be a retina version and yields a 404?

An example of an image block markup follows:

```html
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large">
<noscript>
    <img width="1024" height="920" 
        src="/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/motorcycle.jpg" 
        alt="" class="wp-image-14392" 
        srcset="/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/motorcycle.jpg 1024w, /wp-content/uploads/2021/01/motorcycle-300x270.jpg 300w, /wp-content/uploads/2021/01/motorcycle-768x690.jpg 768w, /wp-content/uploads/2021/01/motorcycle-860x773.jpg 860w, /wp-content/uploads/2021/01/motorcycle-680x611.jpg 680w, /wp-content/uploads/2021/01/motorcycle-250x225.jpg 250w, /wp-content/uploads/2021/01/motorcycle-50x45.jpg 50w" 
        sizes="(max-width: 1024px) 100vw, 1024px" />
</noscript>
<img width="1024" height="920" src='data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20viewBox=%220%200%201024%20920%22%3E%3C/svg%3E' 
    data-src="/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/motorcycle.jpg" alt="" class="lazyload wp-image-14392" 
    data-srcset="/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/motorcycle.jpg 1024w, /wp-content/uploads/2021/01/motorcycle-300x270.jpg 300w,  /wp-content/uploads/2021/01/motorcycle-76x68.jpg 76w, /wp-content/uploads/2021/01/motorcycle-50x45.jpg 50w" 
    data-sizes="(max-width: 1024px) 100vw, 1024px" />
<figcaption>Motorcycle</figcaption>
```